# Objective-C:How to define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH for both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ipad

I would like to set a condition for these values:

```
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 35.0f
```

Is it possible to change values according to the device?

Comment: Do you have different targets for iPhone and iPad? Or a single target (universal app)?

Comment: It would be much easier if you used auto sizing masks for your widths.

Comment: Did you mean these ones? self.view.bounds.size.width/ self.view.bounds.size.height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

if(IS_IPAD)
       // use ipad widht and height
else
     // use iphone widht and height
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have different targets try something like

```
#ifdef iPHONE_APP 
    #define ...
#elif iPAD_APP
    #define ...
#else
    #define ...
#endif
```

Then define X_APP in your preprocessor macro of each target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to change the resolution accordingly to the device type (iPhone/iPad) :

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad code
    screenHeight = 1024;
    screenWidth = 768.;

} else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // iPhone or iPod Touch code
    screenWidth = 320.;
    screenHeight = 480.;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a universal app, then you differentiate between the iPad and the iPhone at build time. So you can't make `#define`s with different values for the two devices.

However you can determine the type of the device at runtime using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // iPhone
    // ...
} else {
    // iPad
    // ...
}
```

320 is also the width of the iPhone screen. So if you want your cells to have the width of the device screen, you can determine that like this:

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```